# Eclipse Scout Neon row index in form data

Tags: indexing, row, eclipse-scout

I would like to know how to get row index from form data of the table field.

I would like to get row index from `MyTableRowData` and I can't find function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, the list of rows is stored as a `List<AbstractTableRowData>`.
When you invoke the method `getRows()` on an `AbstractTableFieldBeanData`, you get an array that is ordered in the same way as the corresponding list.
There is yet another method `rowAt(int i)` that gets you the row at index `i`.

The individual row data object, however, does not know its row index.

You may want to explain your use case. This could help to help you :-)